# FormatException error in flutter dart , CSV file

Tags: flutter, csv, dart, error-handling, format

I'm having a problem with my CSV file in flutter dart.
So this is my main where I have my list where I declared seven variables. Three ints and four strings.
When I try executing my code, they give me this error coming from the CSV file. I tried several times, and sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't, even though it's the same data, and it gives me the format exception error.
Please, if someone can detect the error, I really tried to find what I'm doing wrong, but I can't find the error.

Thanks for helping. I have attached the error and my main code [image]

[image]

this is my decision map(dummy data)[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are having issues with parsing ints. Without seeing all the data, it is impossible to know where. So either step and debug, or try parsing instead, or perhaps both.

Instead of `int.parse(...)` you could do `int.tryParse(...) ?? 0`

Comment: It is still not working; my data is stored in a hive database. The app works with the dummy data that I wrote at the beginning when I was building the app. Once I delete this data and copy and paste the map that I want, it gives me the format error. I don't know if the database has a relation to this error